# Create a list that returns only palindromes from a list of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list, palindrome

I'm working on creating a program that will first check if numbers in the list are palindromes and then prints out only the palindromes. I am new to Python so I'm not sure how to properly append these to a new list.

```
inp= input()

list1 = []
while int(inp) != 0:
    list1.append(inp)
    inp= input()

def isPalindrome(N): 
    str1 = "" + str(N) 
    len1 = len(str1) 
    for i in range(int(len1 / 2)): 
        if (str1[i] != str1[len1 - 1 - i]): 
            return False
    return True

list2 = []

for i in list1:
    if i == isPalindrome:
        list2.append(i(list1))

print(list2)
```

For example,

Input:

```
99
23
45
1221
0
```

Output:

```
99 1221
```

Comment: You're using `if i == isPalindrome:` when you need to be using `if isPalindrome(i):`. Also, it should just be `list2.append(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have some syntax errors in your code but your logic is correct..
Here is what you intended to do,

```
inp= int(input())

list1 = []
while inp != 0:
    list1.append(inp)
    inp = int(input())

def isPalindrome(N):
    str1 = "" + str(N)
    len1 = len(str1)
    for i in range(int(len1 / 2)):
        if (str1[i] != str1[len1 - 1 - i]):
            return False
    return True

list2 = []

for i in list1:
    if isPalindrome(i):
        list2.append(i)

print(list2)
```

Also if you want to make your program much shorter than i recommend this,

```
def isPalindrome(N):
    str1 = str(N)
    if str1[::-1] == str1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Just a slight change in synatx but logic is though same as yours. It uses string slicing in reverse direction.

Also i have type casted the input to integers using `int(input())` as you said you need numbers to be printed in `list2`, if you don't want integers then just replace all `int(input())` with `input()` and change your if condition to `int(inp)!=0` at beginning